# How to generate points on a line? in Processing

Tags: processing

I’m trying to make 6 dots along a line(0, random(height), width, random(height)). The dots should be evenly spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lerp(start, end, t)`](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) to linearly interpolate between to values by specifying `t`: where in between the start/end values you'd like the result to be.

This `t` value is between `0.0` and `1.0` (normalised value). You can think if of it as percentage. (e.g. 0.0 is at the start (0%) value, 1.0 is at the end value(100%), 0.5 is 50% between the start and end value).

In your case, you would:

1. store the randomly generated values first (before interpolation)
2. iterate 6 times, and for each iteration
3. for each iteration, map the iteration index to the normalised value (`t`)
   Finally, use `lerp()` by plugging in the from/to values and the `t` value at the current iteration.

Here's a basic example:

```java
float fromX = 0;
float fromY = random(height);

float toX = width;
float toY = random(height);

int numPoints = 6;
for(int i = 0 ; i < numPoints; i++){
  float interpolationAmount = map(i, 0, numPoints - 1, 0.0, 1.0); 
  
  float interpolatedX = lerp(fromX, toX, interpolationAmount);
  float interpolatedY = lerp(fromY, toY, interpolationAmount);
  
    ellipse(interpolatedX, interpolatedY, 9, 9);
}
```

Alternatively you can use [PVector's `lerp`()](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_lerp_.html) to easiely interpolate between points in 2D (or 3D), without having to interpolate every component:

```java
PVector start = new PVector(0    , random(height));
PVector end   = new PVector(width, random(height));

for(float t = 0.0 ; t <= 1.0 ; t += 1.0 / 5){
  PVector inbetween = PVector.lerp(start, end, t);
  ellipse(inbetween.x, inbetween.y, 9, 9);
}
```

**Update**
The [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope#Definition) is the ratio (division) between the difference on Y axis (called rise, Δy = y2 - y1 (E.g. `toY - fromY`)) and the difference on the X axis (called run, Δx = x2 - x1 (e.g. `toX - fromX`)).

You can use this difference between start and end points (defining the slope) to draw the points in between.
If you divide this difference into equal sections, each for a point you'd like to draw, then you can multiply it as you iterate and simply translate/offset it from the start position:

```java
// start point
float fromX = 0;
float fromY = random(height);
// end point
float toX = width;
float toY = random(height);
// difference between each component
float diffY = toY - fromY;
float diffX = toX - fromX;
// slope = ratio between Y and X difference
float slope = diffY / diffX;

println("slope as ratio", slope, "as degrees", degrees(atan2(diffY, diffX) + PI));

// start drawing 6 points
int numPoints = 6;
// precalculate a sixth
float sectionIncrement = 1.0 / (numPoints - 1);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 6; i++){
  // a sixth incremented (e.g. 1/6 * 0, * 1, *2, ...)
  float section = sectionIncrement * i;
  // a sixth incremented and mulitplied to the difference
  // e.g. 1/6 of slope difference, 2/6 of slope / etc.
  // to which we offset the start location (fromX, fromY +)
  float x = fromX + (diffX * section);
  float y = fromY + (diffY * section);
  // render
  ellipse(x, y, 9, 9);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there another way to do it? Using the slope?

Comment: Happy to hear the answer was helpful: feel free to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (and tick the greenmark if/when it resolves your issue). I think it should be possible. Out of curiosity: is this for an assignment ? (e.g. are you constraint to using slope instead of lerp?)

Comment: Yes it is for an assignment. I cannot use leap :(

Comment: I've added an update above with notes on slope with notes/comments and a link. There are slight variations on the same way of computing slope. Hopefully that is clear and you can adapt it any way required by the assignment. In the future, do mention the assignment in the question, the constraints and ideally your attempt at tacking it with what didn't work acording to plan and how you expected it to work. When you get a chance, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to make most of this website (as it behaves differently from forums/etc.). Welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
point(0, random(height))
point(width/5, random(height))
point(width/5*2, random(height))
point(width/5*3, random(height))
point(width/5*4, random(height))
point(width, random(height))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the points are not on the line because of the y (random(height)).